# Linq query in C# to retrieve the set of elements with respect to list

Tags: c#, linq

We have the list A which contain the random indexes in it. I have another list B which contains the class objects in it. I want to parse list B with the indexes present in list A and find the objects which have name Amar in it using Linq.

For example:

```
List<int> Indexes = new List<int>();   // This contains the random indexes
List<Student> StuObj = new List<Student>();

Class Student
{ 
    String name;
}
```

Now I want to parse the list `StuObj` with the respect to the indexes present in the list `Indexes` and get the `Student` object indexes present in the list `StuObj` where the name is `Amar`.

Comment: Could you provide some code and give some examples? What the class objects do you have? Do you really need to use Linq for it?

Comment: Are you saying you want to find the element in StuObj where: 

the index of the element in StuObj is in indexes
AND
the name of the student is Amar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using Linq. The `Where` has an overload that provides the index of the element:

```
List<int> indexes = new List<int>() { 5, 1 , 10, 30 };

var results = listB.Where((item, index)=> indexes.Contains(index) 
                                       && item.Name == "Amar")
                   .Select(x => listB.IndexOf(x)).To‌​List();
```

Edit: to get the index of the element in the original `listB`, you can make use of the `IndexOf(T)` method.

Comment: How to get the index of object instead of objects

Comment: @G.T. Well you can replace `.ToList()` with `.Select(x=> listB.IndexOf(x)).ToList();`

Comment: @G.T. You justed accepted an answer that produces wrongs results. `.Select((item, index) => index)` selects the index of the filtered set, so you'll always get 0,1,2,3 etc... till the number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var result = listA
    .Where(i => i >= 0 && i < listB.Count)
    .Select(i => listB[i])
    .FirstOrDefault(b => b.Name == "Amar");
```

Basically you use the value from `listA` as index of an element of the `listB`. If you are sure that `listA` contains only valid indexes, then `Where` call can be removed.

**EDIT:** As per updated question, the answer is even easier:

```
var result = listA
    .Where(i => i >= 0 && i < listB.Count && listB[i].Name == "Amar")
    .ToList();
```

I see absolutely no reason to use the linear searching (hence slow) methods `Contains` and `IndexOf` as suggested in some other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have two lists, List indexList and List dataList, you can use select as follows:

```
indexList.Select(i => dataList[i]);
```

You should consider what you wish to happen if indexList contains an integer < 0 or > the size of dataList. For example, you could replace invalid entries with null, like:

```
indexList.Select(i => i < 0 || i >= dataList.Count ? null : dataList[i]);
```

Or you could filter them out like:

```
indexList.Where(i => i>=0 && i < dataList.Count).Select(i => dataList[i]);
```

Or you may know via preconditions that you will never have items in the index list that are out of the range of valid values.

EDIT
Based on the updated question, try this:

```
dataList.Where((item, index) => indexList.Contains(index) && item.Name == "Amar")
    .Select(item => dataList.IndexOf(item));
```

This takes advantage of the Select and Where overloads that take the index of the item. The Where clause selects the item where the item's index in dataList is in the indexList, and also where the item's Name is Amar. The Select clause then returns the index of the item in the original data list.

Comment: This gives the wrong results, since the last select produces the index in the filtered list.

Comment: You are correct, thanks. Fixed the code to use IndexOf

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var result = Indexes
    .Select(i => StuObj[i])
    .Where(s => s.name = "Amar").ToList()
```

It performs fast index lookup to fetch only required objects. If you know there is only one record, you can use `First` or `FirstOrDefault` instead of `ToList`.